# Sitecore publishing service dialog languages order

Tags: publishing

Where is the order of languages in `Publish Item` dialog defined?

And what would be the way to amend it i.e. make it the same order as languages under `/sitecore/system/Languages`?

Couldn't find anything about the topic online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### tl/dr;

You can't change the order without custom code.

#### The Why?

When the `Publish` form builds the language list, it first calls:

```
LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Context.ContentDatabase);
```

Then orders then using:

```
languages.OrderBy(l => l.GetDisplayName())
```

Unfortunately, `.GetDisplayName()` does not get the display name of the item, but the display name of the `CultureInfo` of the language code:

```
/// <summary>Gets the display name.</summary>
/// <param name="cultureInfo">The culture info.</param>
/// <returns>The display name.</returns>
public static string GetDisplayName(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) cultureInfo, nameof (cultureInfo));
    if ((cultureInfo.CultureTypes & CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture) != CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture)
        return cultureInfo.EnglishName + " : " + cultureInfo.NativeName;
    return "{0} : {1}".FormatWith((object) cultureInfo.Name, (object) cultureInfo.NativeName);
}
```

So the only way to change it would be to override the default `Publish` dialog and create your own to order the languages differently.